# VK Like Widget: show 0 instead of +1

Tags: vk, social-media-like

In VK Like Widget, in counters, is there any way to show 0 instead of +1 when nobody likes item? I'm initializing my button via

```
VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like", {type: "button", pageUrl: absUrl});
```